# Adicionar tupla em conjunto Python

Tags: python, dicionário, grafo, tupla, set

Estou criando um grafo com as seguintes regras:

- O grafo é um dicionário.
- Os vértices são as chaves desse dicionário e os valores são as arestas.
- Como eu posso ter mais de uma aresta para um vértice, preciso criar um conjunto `set()` para os valores do dicionário.

O problema diz ainda que as arestas precisam conter vértices e 'pesos' e que portanto é necessário colocá-los em tuplas dentro desse conjunto.

Não sei se está claro, mas o código de implementação para adicionar arestas é o seguinte:

- `self.grafo` é o dicionário.
- `vert_Origem` é 'Jim' - Jim já é um vértice incluído no dicionário
- `vert_Destino` é 'Liam'

```
def addArestas (self, vert_Origem, vert_Destino, peso=1):
     for key, value in self.grafo.items(): 
        aresta= tuple()
        aresta = (vert_Destino, peso)
        value.add(aresta)
        self.graph[vert_Origem] = aresta
     return True
```

Acontece que ele retorna todas as chaves com todas as arestas. Não estou conseguindo colocar as arestas específicas para cada vértice.

Quando eu coloco:

```
def addArestas (self, vert_Origem, vert_Destino, peso=1):
     for key, value in self.grafo.items(): 
        aresta= tuple()
        aresta = (vert_Destino, peso)
        conjunto = set()
        conjunto.add(aresta)
        self.graph[vert_Origem] = conjunto 
     return True
```

O método me retorna apenas a última aresta, sobrescrevendo as outras entradas.

Alguém consegue identificar o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, existem dois erros que você está cometendo:

1. Você está iterando sobre as chaves do dicionário sem necessidade. No primeiro código, isso faz com que você adicione a nova aresta para todos os nodos do grafo (e note que você nem usa as variáveis `key` e `value` no seu segundo código).
2. No segundo código, você cria um novo `set` cada vez que adiciona uma nova aresta, o que faz com que as arestas que já existiam ali sejam perdidas.

O que voce deve fazer é:

1. Recuperar o `set` correspondente ao `vert_Origem`, criando um novo apenas caso seja a primeira aresta do nodo.
2. Atualizar esse `set` com o novo element `(vert_Destino, peso)`

```
def addArestas(self, vert_Origem, vert_Destino, peso=1):
    aresta = (vert_Destino, peso)

    if vert_Origem not in self.grafo: # Cria o set apenas se essa eh a primeira aresta do nodo.
        self.grafo[vert_Origem] = set()

    self.grafo[vert_Origem].add(aresta)

    return True
```

Note também que você não precisa criar uma tupla vazia `tuple()` antes de criar a tupla `(vert_Destino, peso)`, pois ela simplesmente vai ser sobrescrita pelo novo objeto.

Uma outra coisa que eu te aconselho a tomar cuidado é quando usar um `set` cujo elementos são tuplas. Caso você insira um elemento `(4, 5)` (i.e., aresta pro vértice 4 com peso 5) e depois você decida modificar o peso dessa aresta (e.g., peso 6), não adianta simplesmente inserir um novo elemento `(4, 6)`, pois o Python vai manter ambos os elementos no `set` (pois eles são distintos). Não sei qual o motivo de você estar usando `set` ao invés de `list`, mas se for para garantir que não haja duas arestas ligando os mesmo vértices, isso não vai funcionar.

A propósito, em um momento você usa `self.grafo` e em outro `self.graph`. Isso pode estar causando algum bug também.

Comment: Leafar, entendi a lógica, obrigado. Sobre a utilização de tuplas em set(), você quer dizer que se eu tiver que modificar o peso da aresta eu terei que remover a aresta atual primeiro antes de inserir a nova?

Comment: Sim, se voce inserir a tupla `(4, 5)` e depois inserir a tupla `(4, 6)`, ambas continuarão no set, pois elas não são exatamente iguais. O que voce pode fazer é armazenar apenas o nodo de destino no set, se tornando assim um set de inteiros e não de tuplas. Para armazenar os pesos, voce pode criar um novo dicionario `dict_pesos` que mapeia tuplas com os nodos de cada aresta `(nodo1, nodo2)` para o valor do peso correspondente.